# MS SQL (SAP B1) "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I've used this SQL query for the SAP B1 database, that should run the different queries depends on the user's group:

```
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN T0.GroupId = '2'
           THEN
(
    SELECT T0.Substitute, 
           T0.ItemCode, 
           T1.ItemName
    FROM OSCN T0
         INNER JOIN OITM T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
    WHERE T0.CardCode = 'CV-1234'
)
           ELSE(CASE
                    WHEN(T0.GroupId = '4')
                    THEN
(
    SELECT T0.ItemCode
    FROM OSCN T0
    WHERE T0.CardCode = 'CV-1234'
)
                    ELSE ''
                END)
       END
FROM OUGR T0
     INNER JOIN USR7 T1 ON T1.UserId = T1.UserId
WHERE T1.UserId = 'George'
```

But when I run it, I get an error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS".

Appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplified repro `select case when 1=2 then 'a' else (select 1,2) end`  You just can't use CASE like that.  Can you explain with sample data and expected results what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I used this query for the formatted search in SAP B1 (Service Call):  in the field ItemCode field when the user types the Item code and hit Tab, the query should show the list of results, depends on the user's group:
- Group 2: 
           Substitute (BP Code), 
           ItemCode, 
           ItemName
- Group 4: 
           ItemCode,
           ItemName.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write SQL like this. If you consider a very simple SQL template:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
WHERE x = y;
```

a and b can only be single values; if you think about it, having 'a' correspond to multiple values (by which I mean multiple columns) makes no sense. There is no such thing as dynamic SQL where the structure of a SQL statement (or the structure of its result) is indeterminate at the point of execution or could change from row to row (you can dynamically construct a SQL statement but is fixed at the point is it executed).

So you can substitute 'a' with as complex SQL as you like but that SQL must always result in a single value.

No idea if it is supported in your SAPB1 environment but the usual way of dealing with something like this would be to wrap it in code (PL/SQL in Oracle, T-SQL in SQL Server, etc) - so your code determines which of the SQL Statements in your CASE statement to execute and then just executes that 1 statement